# How can a button visible only on given month and date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a button to be visible on given date and month with javascript.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function today()
{
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();


if(month==1 && day==1)
{ 
document.getElementById('xx').style.visibility='visible';
}
else
{
document.getElementById('xx').style.visibility='hidden';
}
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="image" SRC="/Patankar/PNH/images/click_anim.gif"   id="xx"  id="return1" onClick='today();' ALT="Submit Form" style="visibility:hidden;display:none" >
```

I tried this code but nothing happened. Please tell me my mistake.

Comment: Don't do this in JavaScript. People will hack past it too easily. Save the bandwidth and client processing by not sending the button from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `id` tags on one element:

```
id="xx"  id="return1"
```

Remove one of them. From your code example, you should remove `id="return1"`.

Comment: I removed return1 still it doesn't work. Will it appear on the given date by using above code?